# React / Firebase problem: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

My React application worked perfectly fine until I started uploading it on Firebase.

After setting the API key and configuring my database settings in store.js (firebaseConfig), the hell broke loose and
I cannot start my application. It doesn't work anymore when I start it, and obviously I cannot upload it.
It is a CRUD application. I am attaching the screenshot of the error.[image: Error]

Did anyone have this kind of problem?

console log
[image: console log (inspect)]

Comment: what is the value of client? Can you console.log it. You probably can't fetch clients correctly or data is somehow different than expected.

Comment: const { clients } = props; I can't console log it now, since I got another error in the meantime, it says there is no index.html. Suddenly it disappeared, I have no idea how...

Comment: What do you see when you type `console.log(clients)` in your code.

Comment: hm, it says "'clients' is not defined  no-undef"...

Comment: That's why it throws the error there is no `clients.konto` so it can't make it a string. You are having a problem with fetching the data. Provide some code so we can help.

Comment: omg I figured it out...It was capital K in my database, and in the application it was lower case k...What a small little thing makes an app impossible to run, amazing...thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: No problem. These things happen, good luck with your project :)